# How to push all objects into another array using javascript Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I web API call and in the background, it's running more than one time. So I received the response **commentRows** as data which I mention.

I have to map those data into another array.

```
var arrPush =[ ]; 
var commentRows ={  
   '@odata.context':'https:indexes',
   value:[  
      {  
         "key":"176611",
         "status":true,
         "errorMessage":null,
         "statusCode":200
      },
      {  
         "key":"176100",
         "status":true,
         "errorMessage":null,
         "statusCode":200
      }
   ]
}; 

arrPush.push(commentRows.value);
```

It generates the array for as,

```
[  
   [  
      {  
         "key":"176611",
         "status":true,
         "errorMessage":null,
         "statusCode":200
      },
      {  
         "key":"176100",
         "status":true,
         "errorMessage":null,
         "statusCode":200
      }
   ]
]
```

Needed

```
   [  
      {  
         "key":"176611",
         "status":true,
         "errorMessage":null,
         "statusCode":200
      },
      {  
         "key":"176100",
         "status":true,
         "errorMessage":null,
         "statusCode":200
      }
   ]
```

but I don't want the first [] has to be appended Can I use any **Lodash** for achieving this

Comment: updated question

Comment: `arrPush.push(commentRows.value[0]);` Do not use lodash for this

Comment: it may be [{"key":"176611","status":true,"errorMessage":null,"statusCode":200},{"key":"176100","status":true,"errorMessage":null,"statusCode":207}] sometime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an solution which can handle **multiple** elements in `value` array:

use [_.flatten](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#flatten):

```
var arrPush = [];
var commentRows = {  
       '@odata.context':'https:indexes',
       value:[  
          {  
             "key":"176611",
             "status":true,
             "errorMessage":null,
             "statusCode":200
          }
       ]
    };

arrPush.push(commentRows.value);
arrPush = _.flatten(arrPush);  // here you get it
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arrPush = [];
var commentRows = {  
  '@odata.context':'https:indexes',
  value:[  
    {  
       "key":"176611",
       "status":true,
       "errorMessage":null,
       "statusCode":200
    }
  ]
};

commentRows.value.forEach(x => arrPush.push(x))
console.log(arrPush);
```

Use a `forEach` loop and push them into `arrPush`

Answer (score 0):

Just push like this arrPush.push(commentRows.value[0]);

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
arrPush = _.concat(arrPush, commentRows.value[0]).
```

Here arrayToCopy is the array to which you want to copy the data.

Comment: You didn't declared arrayToCopy. Right?